# Allow propagation again

Tags: jquery

I disable propagation of `click`s.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#user-wrapper .dropdown-menu').click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
```

How can I enable it again?

Let's say I'd like to have 2 functions: `stopPropagation()` and `enablePropagation()`

Comment: on what basis you want to stop/start propagation?

Comment: Let's say I'd like to have 2 functions: `stopPropagation()` and `enablePropagation()`

Comment: are you trying to disable or enable menu items/menubar ?

Comment: Provide use case because there is for sure better to do than what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @A.Wolff I already accepted the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once propagation has been stopped, it cannot be resumed. As a workaround, what you can do is set a variable, and then only stop if this variable is true:

```
var stop = false;
// do your logic here
if(stop){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

#### Solution #2

Or you may try this in another way

```
$('#some_link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#some_link').unbind('click'); //worked as the only method to restore the default action.
```

Your call!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx, Toan, I used the first solution.